# jQuery options object reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, object

When dealing with jQuery options object, should I reference the "global" ResponsiveMenu every time or create a "local" copy of the option I need in each module?

Have a look at the code and let me know which you think is best and why, or if it even matters at all. The way I've been doing it is: if I use the reference more than once, I make a "local" copy. If I only use it once, I'll reference the "global" one.

```
ResponsiveMenu = {

    init: function(options, elem) {
        this.options = $.extend( {}, this.options, options );
        this.elem = $(elem);

        this.bindEvents();

        return this;
    },

    options: {
        trigger: null,
        activeClass: 'active',
        submenuTrigger: $('.sub-toggle')
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        var self = this;

        this.options.trigger.on('click', triggerMain(evt, self));
    },

    triggerMain: function(evt, self) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        var activeClass = self.options.activeClass;

        self.elem.toggleClass(activeClass);
        self.options.trigger.toggleClass(activeClass); //"Global" reference

    },
}
```

OR this:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    var self = this,
        trigger = this.options.trigger; //"Local" copy

    trigger.on('click', triggerMain(evt, self, trigger));
},


triggerMain: function(evt, self, trigger) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var activeClass = self.options.activeClass;

    self.elem.toggleClass(activeClass);
    trigger.toggleClass(activeClass);

},
```

Comment: Your strategy ("*if used multiple times, dereference to local variable*") is fine. Yet, the only difference between your two codes seems to be the additional parameter to `triggerMain` and has not much to do with your question?

Comment: To me it looks like it's totally the same for a small number of references to the global variable. You won't really see any performance changes (or memory waste anyway) by deferencing to local variables if the number of times you use the global variable is small (like in the provided example).

Comment: Also notice that the `on` method expects a plain function for the handler argument, you are already calling it (and passing the result of the invocation).

Comment: This is just an example. I can't know how many times the object will be referenced yet because this code will likely be extended and functionality will be added. Thus, adding more references. I wanted to start well so that later on I don't run into a wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks primarily like a style question. Generally I only define a variable if I need to access that same value more than once. When referencing a function you will also run into scope issues. For example in this case:

```
var obj = {
    num: 2,
    trigger: function() {
        console.log(this.num);
    }
}

obj.trigger();
```

It will log `2` to the console because the function is bound to `obj` as the scope. If you do

```
var t = obj.trigger;
t();
```

however, you will get `undefined` because the default scope for a function is the `window` object. In ECMAScript 5 you can tell what to bind the function to like this:

```
var t = obj.trigger.bind(obj);
t();
```

Which will now log `2`.

Comment: Good information! I didn't realize this and probably will save my ass later on :)